# css inconsistency between chrome and safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari

im having trouble with my css displaying correctly in both Chrome and Safari.
Because they are both webkit browsers i cant understand why.

My css positioning and div size displays perfectly in both FireFox and Safari but is all out of wak in chrome.

I have tried css reset but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

The website is here

[www.girlsskateaustralia.com](http://www.girlsskateaustralia.com)

Comment: What results are you expecting? What results are you getting? What code shows the problems?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me in Chrome on Mac.